# How to split multiple commands according to PEP8?

Tags: python, pep8

I have the following command:

```
DataFrame = df0.join(df1, how = 'outer').join(df2, how = 'outer').join(df3, how = 'outer').....
```

I know I could split it up, like this:

```
dataFrame = df0.join(df1, how = 'outer')
dataFrame = dataFrame.join(df2, how = 'outer')
dataFrame = dataFrame.join(df3, how = 'outer')
...
```

But I'm not sure what PEP8 says about this, what is the preferred method to not exceed the 79 char limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The **preferred way** of wrapping long lines is by using Python's **implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces**. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.
>
> Backslashes may still be appropriate at times. For example, long, multiple `with`-statements cannot use implicit continuation, so backslashes are acceptable:
>
> ```
> with open('/path/to/some/file/you/want/to/read') as file_1, \
>      open('/path/to/some/file/being/written', 'w') as file_2:
>     file_2.write(file_1.read())
> ```
>
> Another such case is with `assert` statements.
>
> Make sure to indent the continued line appropriately. The preferred place to break around a binary operator is after the operator, not before it.
>
> — https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

I.e. for your example:

```
dataFrame = (df0.join(df1, how='outer').
                 join(df2, how='outer').
                 join(df3, how='outer'))
```

Comment: Actually it's not an argument, so it might be okay.

Comment: @pacholik, actually, I am not sure what is normatively correct. I guess it is more readable if you put the first `join()` on same line, so *want* it to be okay this way. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Insert newlines after the dots. If you surround the whole statement with paratheses, you won't even need trailing backslashes.

```
dataFrame = (df0.
             join(df1, how='outer').
             join(df2, how='outer').
             join(df3, how='outer'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, I did not realise the paratheses would work like this. Good thing to know!

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't create dummy variables just to satisfy PEP.
However, what is suggested here is to split the command on several *lines*.

```
DataFrame = df0.join(df1, how = 'outer') \
               .join(df2, how = 'outer') \
               .join(df3, how = 'outer')
```

Finally, in some case you can't make lines shorter than 80 chars!

Comment: "Finally, in some case you can't make lines shorter than 80 chars!" Could you give an example for that? I don't think that is true unless your variable names are longer that 78 characters.

Comment: Also, while I prefer putting the dots on the newline, too, it is not recommended by PEP-8.

Comment: Long lines when class/methods ident already eat space, long list comprehensions that look worse on multiline (subjective), accessing private methods, etc.

Comment: @Kay ok didn't know about dots on newlines. My flake8 doesn't complain.

Comment: In such cases you should refactor your code. When your indention approaches the line limit, then your code is probably entirely unreadable.